# Adding a colored strip on the top of Adaptive card

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, teams-toolkit

I wanted to add colored strips to the top of an adaptive card that I am trying to make. It should be something like the yellow and blue strips on the cards made by the Azure DevOps extension.

[Click on this image to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMx21.png)

Can anyone give any idea how to do so?

Comment: Could you please check if [accentColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#accentcolor), helps? Color mentioned for accentColor will be used as a background for your outline icons. Thanks

Comment: Hii @Meghana-MSFT, I don't want to change the color of my outline icons, but instead I want to add a colorful strip at the top of my adaptive card, like the blue and yellow strips in the cards shown in the above picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMx21.png)

Comment: See the accepted answer to a similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74129567/how-to-get-microsoft-teams-card-to-display-correctly

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

[image]

Not exactly what you want but currently i don't know how you could do a thinner line. Colors can only be the already existing ones like accent, warning etc. Code for the line is just like this:

```
    {
        "type": "Container",
        "style": "good",
        "bleed": true,
        "spacing": "None"
    },
```

The only other option is to create an image of the line you like to have, like a 5px png and add it to the card.

Answer (score 0):

To add a blue strip over every adaptive card you need to add the `ancent color` property to the manifest file.